# Geometry book for the university with solved exercises (affine space, euclidean space, etc...)

Tags: geometry, soft-question, affine-geometry

I'm looking for a book with solved exercises of affine space, affine transformations, etc... I found a lot of books and pdf's with theory, but none of them contained solved exercises, and I'm having difficulties solving the problems of my exercises' list.

Could anybody recommend me one?

Thanks!